# History of languages from a geographical perspective

Tags: historical-linguistics, comparative-linguistics, history

Unfortunately I am totally unaware of the research and most of the basic methodology of Linguistics, but I am really keen on knowing more about languages because I am a passionate learner of new ones, and I find etymology to be the main source of my interest, as well as one of the tools that help me more in learning a new language. Also the comparison between languages words and grammars, fascinate me, and I very often find myself interested and keen on studying a new language only under the push of the enthusiasm that these comparisons hint at.

Therefore, my question concerns references. Where to look for books (and any other kind of material) on *comparative* linguistics (accessible to a non-expert), especially on the hidden influences that are clearly visible to anyone who, like me, starts to venture into the realm of languages.

I have also been wondering for a while if there are any not-too-technical references on the history of languages from a geographical point of view. For example, how migrations and wars , colonisations, etc. influenced the melting, mixing, distortions of different languages.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Quite a lot of work has been done in the cross-over area between archeology and etymology, investigating what words for what things can be reconstructed for early languages, then looking at the archeological evidence for the existence of those things in the areas those languages might have been spoken.  I won't try to answer this, but I hope someone can give you some good references.

Answer (score 3):

Nicholas Ostler's *Empires of the Word* should fit the bill.

Comment: I was thinking of that one too.